# Pass values from a row to another JSP using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I'm trying to get row values from a bootstrap table to send them to another JSP document while using jQuery, however seems like I can't find a proper way to do that.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <%
                    int serial = 0;
                    int id = 0;
                    String name = null;
                    double ammount = 0;
                    String date = null;
                    User user = null;
                %>
                <tr>
                    <th><%="Serial"%></th>
                    <th><%="Cost ID"%></th>
                    <th><%="Cost Name"%></th>
                    <th><%="Cost Ammount"%></th>
                    <th><%="Cost Date"%></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%
                    try {
                        int id_id = (int) session.getAttribute("id");
                        List<Object[]> costs = scm.viewAll(sum.getUser(id_id));
                        for (Object[] cost : costs) {
                            id = (int) cost[0];
                            name = (String) cost[1];
                            ammount = (double) cost[2];
                            date = (String) cost[3];
                            serial += 1;
                %>
                <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="updatesingle">
                    <td><%=serial%></td>
                    <td><%=id%></td>
                    <td><%=name%></td>
                    <td><%=ammount%></td>
                    <td><%=date%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        response.sendRedirect("home");
                    }
                %>
```

This code above is the table code. As you can see the rows are clickable and I'm redirecting to a new page(JSP) when a row clicked, using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        });
    });
```

What I'm trying to do, is to pass for example the Cost ID(id variable) value to the next JSP page and manipulate it in some way, and the value should be of the specific row I clicked on. Is there a way to do so?

P.S I'm new to jQuery so please be gentle :)

Comment: you could append it to the redirect url as a search parameter `url?id=#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the id in a `data-` attribute:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="updatesingle" data-id="<%=id%>">
```

And, if you're going to use that ID with JSP, then you can pass it as a parameter to the other page:

```
window.document.location = $(this).data("href") + "?id=" + $(this).data("id");
```

But if you're going to get it with jQuery in the other page, you can save the ID into the sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('clickedUserID', $(this).data("id"));
window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
```

In the other page, you just get it from the sessionStorage and use it:

```
var userID = sessionStorage.getItem('clickedUserID');
// do something with the ID
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pro-tip:** if you are only printing out a `String` into your JSP, you can simply just type it into the HTML (and save yourself the extra coding)

Here's my attempt to answer your question:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
    // you can add the URL for the new page here like:
    // var newLocation = "<URL for JSP>?paramName=" + paramValue
    // this is just an example of how it would work
    var newLocation = window.document.location + "?href=" + $(this).data("href");
    alert( newLocation );

    // oher values
    console.log( $(this).find("td").eq(1).html() ); // 1 for id column, 2 for name, 3 for amount, etc.
    
    window.document.location = newLocation;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Serial</th>
    <th>Cost ID</th>
    <th>Cost Name</th>
    <th>Cost Amount</th>
    <th>Cost Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="updatesingle1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>id1</td>
    <td>name1</td>
    <td>amount1</td>
    <td>date1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="updatesingle2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>id2</td>
    <td>name2</td>
    <td>amount2</td>
    <td>date2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="updatesingle3">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>id3</td>
    <td>name3</td>
    <td>amount3</td>
    <td>date3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```